# Is it possible to change the text font in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: mobile, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios, push-notification

Is it possible to move the Media image from bottom-right to the left of the Push notification.
and is it  possible to change the text font in Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

In Android, you can take full control of the notification displayed on your device.  If Google allows for the customizations you seek, then you can do whatever you like.  (ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html)